# How to pass object value as key of setState in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I want to pass object value dynamically as key of setState.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    inputFields.forEach((item) => {
      return setState({ ...state, [item.name]: "" });
    });
  }, [])
```

Comment: Your code looks good. Not sure what exactly are you trying to achive.

Comment: You don't need to `return` inside `.forEach`, you're not building an array like `.map` or anything, you're just looping over the array. Also it's better to build the state object, and then set state once using that object. But if you insist on setting state every loop iteration, use the function argument so you're sure the state isn't lost between sets: `setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [item.name]: "" }));`

Answer (score 0):

You can clone, assign and then `setstate`

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const sItem = {...state };
    inputFields.forEach((item) => {
      sItem[item.name] = "";
    });
    setState(sItem)
  }, [])
```